# Content Query WebPart - Group by date - SP2010

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I need to display top X last modified documents and/or publishing pages. They need to be grouped by modified date. As far as I know, the CQWP does not support grouping by date. Is there a workaround available? I guess we need to manipulate the dates before  the XSL is called. Someone already encountered this issue?

Example

**30 November 2012**

Item a

Item b

**16 November 2012**

Item c

Item d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be accomplished with [Calculated field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.aspx) as were suggested before.

### Steps:

- Create calculated column for Modified date using the [formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as shown on picture below

[image]

- Specify this field in Grouping setting for CQWP

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a calculated column from your original date field?

Comment: No, not yet. Thanks for mentioning. If client absolutely wants to group by like this - it's probably better to create a custom webpart it seems.