# Group By Last Modified Date in XSL or Content Query WebPart

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I need to diplay the result of my content query webpart as follows:
**Date modified 1**
Title
Title
**Date modified 2**
Title
Title
Title

I know you can't do a group by on the last modified date in de content query webpart. And to be frank, I really don't want to mess up my content type by using the solution that was given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52907/content-query-webpart-group-by-date-sp2010) (no offense, i just like a clean content type).

Is there anyway I can do the same using my custom XSL file?

Answer (score 2):

You can group your items using [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

Put this line **outside** of the xsl templates:

```
<xsl:key name="ByDate" match="Row" use="@YourDateColumn"/>
```

And draw your items like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ByDate', @YourDateColumn)[1])]">
    --- Draw group header ---
    <xsl:for-each select="key('ByDate', @YourDateColumn)">
        --- Draw item ---
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```